# Can I control my Python script with my Android Phone that's running on my PC

Tags: python, android, python-3.x, libraries, vps

Is there a way that i can control my Python Script using my phone? Either by installing an app or creating one? What i want is to either see the output of my script, or, more preferably, interact with it as well, for example, if my script has input, maybe I can type in the input. I'm wondering if what i would need to do, is maybe get a VPS or something of the sort, and host it on there, and connect my phone to the VPS somehow. I would love input and suggestions. If you have an answer, please tell me what libraries to import and/or install. Thanks.

P.S. I have a Windows 10 PC and a Samsung Android Phone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

There are several options.

I would recommend installing a `ssh server` on your windows computer
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_install_firstuse

Then connect to it with an ssh app like https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sonelli.juicessh&hl=en

Then you see the typical `cmd` on your smartphone, where you can run the python script.